# Rotate image in C# Windows Form from original starting position on Button click

Tags: c#, forms, image, button, image-processing

I have code that rotate my image for desired angle on button click, but when I press button again image is rotated again from new image.

I need to rotate image from original starting position on new button click, or if you like I need to reset my image to it's default value and rotate it again for desired degree.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Refer to this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144106/rotate-image-in-picturebox)

Comment: You obviously need to cache the original image.